# Can't understand this Python syntax

Tags: python, matrix

```
max_rows = 8
max_cols = 4

matrix = [[1] * max_cols for _ in range(max_rows)]
```

I can't understand what is happening with this matrix, can someone explain me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called 'list comprehension'

```py
[1] * max_cols
```

Creates a list of `1`, `max_cols` times, i.e [1, 1, ..., 1] `max_cols` times.

```py
[[1] * max_cols for _ in range(max_rows)]
```

Takes the created list [1, 1, ..., 1] and copies it `max_rows` times (as if it was in a for-loop).

Note: an interesting question arises: why not just do `[[1] * max_cols] * max_rows`?

The answer is that `[...] * n` is replicating the address of `[...]`, `n` times and as such, each change to one of the arrays (a pointer to `[...]`) will be seen in all of the arrays

Comment: Good answer, but little misconception, though : it doesn't copy the list, it generates it max_rows times.

Would have been clearer too if you specified that, when writing `[...] * n`, it's not the list that is replicated, but the address of the list, leading to several elements pointing to the same concrete in-memory list.

Comment: You are correct, I'll change it right away

Answer (score 0):

It's a list comprehension, a way of creating a list.

This is equivalent to :

```
max_rows = 8
max_cols = 4
matrix = []
for _ in range(max_rows):
    matrix.append([1] * max_cols)
```

But it is way shorter to write and faster at execution-time.

`_` is a way of naming loop variables that are not used.